# How to write-host to console all files names that have moved

Tags: powershell

Im trying to log to the console all the file names that were moved in the below job.  If i put `$file` or `$files` after the write-host, it logs the full path and just indicates `*.pdf` moved.  im trying to log to the console each file name that was moved.  Below is my script. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
# Move the printed pdfs to an archive location
$files = "\\fileLocation\Express\*.pdf"

foreach ($file in $files) 
{
try 
    {
 # Move all the files
 move-item $files -Destination '\\networkShare\Archive\express' -Force 

 # Output the logging in the console
 Write-Host ("The file " + $file.$_.Name + " has been moved")
     }
 catch
     {
 Write-Host ($file.$_.Name + $_.Exception.message)
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$files` is a single string. Your `for` does not know that it is a path or anything special. You seem to be treating it like a File Object

If you wanted to list all of the files you need to enumerate those paths first so your loop can process each one individually.

**Note:** that in your loop you had `Move-Item` *$files* which would muddy the waters. You wanted to use `$file` but that still would have not worked the way you expected.

```
foreach ($file in (Get-ChildItem "c:\temp" -Filter "*.pdf")){
    try {
        # Move all the files
        move-item $file -Destination '\\networkShare\Archive\express' -Force 

        # Output the logging in the console
        Write-Host ("The file " + $file.Name + " has been moved")
    } catch {
        Write-Host ($file.Name + $_.Exception.message)
    }
}
```

That will process each file during the loop pass.

Honestly thought if you wanted more verbose output something like robocopy would do this out of the box with more information.

```
robocopy "\\fileLocation\Express\" '\\networkShare\Archive\express' '*.pdf' /MOV
```

You can look more into this via `robocopy /?` or on [Doc.Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy)

Comment: Thanks Matt, that did the trick.  I realized after my whole folder moved (doh) that i needed $file as well, but again thank you for the response and answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
# Move the printed pdfs to an archive location
$files = Get-ChildItem -path "\\fileLocation\Express\*.pdf"

foreach ($file in $files) 
{
try 
    {
 # Move all the files
 move-item $files -Destination '\\networkShare\Archive\express' -Force 

 # Output the logging in the console
 Write-Host ("The file " + $file.Name + " has been moved")
     }
 catch
     {
 Write-Host ($file.Name + $_.Exception.message)
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, unfortunately it didnt return anything.  The output was "The File "blank space" has been moved.  I also have 10 files in there, but it only returned one line.

Comment: That's the issue Matt mentiones, $files is a string, not a files collection produced by a Get-ChildItem

Comment: Try it now. I forgot to add the [Get-ChildItem] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-6) cmdlet. Thanks @LotPings for pointing that out.